# How to set a ethernet device for Internet by force?

Tags: ethernet

Now I'm trying to use two ethernet device.
One is for Internet. The other one is for Embedded Target Board NFS.
Internet is connected by Wifi device.(wlan0)
NFS is connected by LAN CABLE.(eth1)

The problem is when I enable both devices, Ubuntu try to connect internet by eth1(LAN CABLE).
So, I cannot use internet & NFS at once.
Can I set wlan0 to connect internet by force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using NetworkManager,

First Disable the Ethernet device.

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Then go to network manager and select  edit connections and then the ethernet device running on its own LAN.

[Go to the IPV4 tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9naPZ.png)

Select "Routes"

[Check the "Use this connection only for resources on its network". Make sure it is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38qfK.png)

Finally:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Answer (score 0):

By editing the routing table.

First of all take a look at your routing table:

```
sudo route -n
```

You should execute the following command:

```
sudo route add default gw 'your_wifi_router_ip' dev wlan0
```

And you should execute this command to avoid having two internet gw (sometimes this can be a problem):

```
sudo route del default gw 'ethernet_gateway' dev eth0
```